# Apply similar looking styles to AlertDialog box for different Android versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I want to make the AlertDialog box for my app look like the ones on Android > 6.0.0 ( as depicted in the following screenshots) for all lower android version till 4.4.4. I have applied a custom style for the dialog box.

Following is the style in styles.xml for AlertDialog:

```
<style 
    name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_grey</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
</style>
```

Following is how I applied the style in java:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertDialogCustom))
            .setMessage("Why is DialogBox Style Inconsistent through different android versions?")

            // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
            // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //Do Something
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //Do Something
                }
            })
            .show();
```

As a get around I managed to at least change the text color to white on the dark background by using:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        style = android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog;

    else
        style = R.style.AlertDialogCustom;
```

**So far I have tried** making seperate style for lower Android version and apply them via java by detecting Android version. But, I am unable to replicate the style of AlertDialog box on Android 6+ on lower android versions till 4.4.4. And I am unable to find a solution on the internet.

There is an anomaly though; if I apply my custom style on Rate this app provided by [kobakei](https://github.com/kobakei/Android-RateThisApp) the resulting RateThisApp dialog looks the same on all the android versions. So I believe styling the AlertDialog in a particular manner should fix the issue.

**This is what I want - To make the AlertDialog box on Android 4.4.4 and 5.1.0 to look like the one in Android 6.0.0 and higher by using suitable styles. And why does the textColor and textColorPrimary attributes does not get applied on lower android versions?**

If the resource provided in my question is insufficient please let me know in the comment, I will share more details.

Here are the screenshots of AlertDialog box on different Android versions with the same style applied.

- Android >= 6.0.0

[image]

- Android = 5.1.0

[image]

- Android 4.4.4

[image]

Comment: Why not create your custom layout for the AlertDialog and then inflate it when creating the Dialog?

Comment: Ahh! The one thing I missed, I will try it and let know whether this fixes my issue.

Comment: But just for curiosity, why is the mentioned issue occurring?

Comment: I guess it must be because of the light/dark theme that sets the color of the font according

Comment: Strange, because I have explicitly declared the textColor parameter.

Comment: yes, I know... It happened to me sometimes and don't know why. My guessing is 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert' does not specify dark or light and it could be there the issue. That's why I told you about a custom layout, because you can set the color of the TextView right there and not worry about the color scheme

Comment: I did it as you suggested thank you. You would have got +15 if you answered the question xD. Thanks btw.

Comment: I'm glad I were helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more flexibility, you can just create your custom dialog class with a custom layout.
It will give you better control over the way the layout looks.

- You can create very complicated UI in your dialog without writing tons of code
- You can simply call your dialog like this :

`CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog();` 
 `customDialog.show();`

- And you can manage click listeners and more events inside your dialog class instead of adding those code lined inside your activity and make it super big and hard to understand.

**Here is an example:**

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
private ImageView imageView;
private Context dialogContext;

public CustomDialog (@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_size_image_dialog); .. //your layout
    dialogContext = context;
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.full_size_image); //controll your views (use any view, the image view is only an example)
}

public void someMethod() {
}     

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I designed a custom dialog box layout was able to replicate the looks of the dialog box on lower android versions. But, any idea why the attribute textColor(and others as well) was not getting applied to lower Android versions?

Comment: I think that it's related to the device itself, not sure tho.

Comment: Nope, I tested it on various devices running stock Android.